# XMLHttpRequest.send(data) not delivering data to Django view function

Tags: javascript, django, xmlhttprequest, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Using pure Javascript, my goal is to recreate jQuery's .autocomplete() function for displaying a list of suggestions as a user types input into the search bar.

I have written code that listens for "keyup/change/paste/input" events on the input element, i.e search bar. As the user types, I wish to use an XMLHttpRequest GET (or POST) request which will deliver the user's input so far (and information about the search context -- not relevant) to a view function which will in turn filter a Model for objects containing the user's input so far and return those objects in a JSONResponse list to the XMLHttpRequest so that I can display the suggestions on the webpage.

I tried to use both GET and POST requests but the data I wished to send to the view function using XMLHttpRequest.send(data) never seemed to deliver to the view function thus inhibiting my progress. In all attempts, printing request.POST (or request.GET) gave empty an QueryDict: <QueryDict: {}>

Below are some code snippets:

```
\\ The below JS code is run on once the page is ready, i.e fully loaded
addListenerMulti(query, "propertychange change click keyup input paste", function () {
            // check if value has changed...
            if (query.value != oldVal) {
                oldVal = query.value;
                var context_object = JSON.stringify({
                    "query_so_far": encodeURI(query.value),
                    "search_context": encodeURI(document.getElementById("filter").value)
                });
              
                try {
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open("GET", 'url-for-view-function');
                    xhr.onload = function () {
                        if (xhr.status === 200) {
                            console.log(xhr.response);
                        } else if (xhr.status === 500) {
                            console.log(xhr.response);
                        }
                    }
                    xhr.send(context_object);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            }
        })
```

What am I getting wrong and how can I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a GET request. To send the data, I included it in the XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader function which takes in a key, value pair. The thing to note is that the key should be of the format, "Xxxx-Yyyy" or simply "Xxxx".

```
try {
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open("GET", 'autocomplete');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Query-Str", encodeURI(query.value));
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Search-Context", encodeURI(document.getElementById("filter").value))
                    xhr.onload = function () {
                        if (xhr.status === 200) {
                            console.log(xhr.response);
                        } else if (xhr.status === 500) {
                            console.log(xhr.response);
                        }
                    }
                    xhr.send(context_object);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
```